# Blank WP starter theme compatible with Blocks and Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, timber, gutenberg-blocks, podscms

I want to refine my wordpress theme development process which is:

1. To make a unique-creative design with Adobe XD or Figma.
2. To convert it to static HTML using VS Code with Bootstrap.
3. In wordpress, create custom post types with PODS.
4. To convert the static HTML in WP templates with Timber.

Based on my experience, this process is the best for me, but I want to integrate better my themes with WP-Blocks.

So, my question is: there are some clean starter-theme ready to use with blocks to use as the main theme and later extend it with a child theme with my custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most popular Bootstrap theme with Gutenberg support, has very good child theme support. A solid agency has bought the repo and taken over, they recently added bootstrap 5 support. This should help your process:

https://github.com/understrap/understrap

I find it difficult with Gutenberg to use CSS framework, I don't see much benefits since blocks are already using flexbox and grid.

UPDATE: best answer exists here :), https://wptavern.com/ask-the-bartender-is-there-a-starter-for-building-block-themes

Comment: Thanks, I tried understrap and I compare it with cormorant. I'm feeling better with cormorant because is simple and blank-empty theme. Anyway understrap is a good option!

Comment: Nice, I'm going to try cormorant as well out. I noticed it's a full-site editing theme, so keep in mind full-site editing is very new in WP and leverages theme.json for styling and html templates.

Answer (score 0):

I found https://wordpress.org/themes/cormorant/ that works very well with Bootstrap and it's an empty theme so didn't interfere with my design.